# find all columns and tables in a database which contain a particular case sensitive string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I would like to find all the tables in my database where the columns "Column1" & "Column2" contain a specific case sensitive string 'aBcD'.Is there a way to do it ?

I came up with the following query . Any suggestions ?

```
SELECT c.name AS ColName, t.name AS TableName
FROM sys.columns c
    JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE c.name = 'Column1' or c.name = 'Column2' and 
/* column contents is 'aBcD'  */  ?
```

Comment: You probably want to use a cursor to iterate over all tables and look for your value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution could be to iterate over all found tables and check their content like this:

```
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
    SELECT t.name, c.name
    FROM sys.columns c
        JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
    WHERE c.name = 'Column1' or c.name = 'Column2'

OPEN cur
CREATE TABLE #output(tablename nvarchar(255), columnname nvarchar(255))

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max), @tab nvarchar(max), @col nvarchar(max)

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @tab, @col

WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0) BEGIN
    SET @sql = N'
        IF(SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM '+@tab+'
        WHERE '+@col+' = N''aBcD''
        COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS) > 0
        INSERT INTO #output(tablename, columname)
        VALUES(N'''+@tab+''',N'''+@col+''')'

    EXEC(@sql)

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @tab, @col
END

SELECT * FROM #output

-- Cleanup
CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur

DROP TABLE #output
```

Answer (score 0):

My buddy Chris Morris at [sqlservercentral.com](http://www.sqlservercentral.com) posted this a few years ago. I modified it slightly to be a little more flexible. This will generate a series of select statements which is much faster than using a cursor. If you wanted to you could shove the results of this into a variable and execute it. Or you can just copy and paste several of these into another query window and run them.

```
DECLARE @MySearchCriteria VARCHAR(500)
SET @MySearchCriteria = '''This user registration has been rejected''' --you do need all these quotation marks because this string is injected to another string.

SELECT 'SELECT ' + c.columnlist + '] FROM [' + t.name + '] WHERE ' + w.whereclause + ';'  as SelectStatement
FROM sys.tables t 
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT STUFF((    
        SELECT '], [' + c.Name AS [text()]
        FROM sys.columns c
        join sys.types t2 on t2.user_type_id = c.user_type_id
        WHERE t.object_id = c.object_id 
            AND c.collation_name IS NOT NULL
            AND c.max_length > 6
            and t2.name not in ('text', 'ntext')
        FOR XML PATH('') 
    ), 1, 2, '' )
) c (columnlist)
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT STUFF((    
        SELECT ' OR [' + c.Name + '] IN (' + @MySearchCriteria + ')' AS [text()]
        FROM sys.columns c
        join sys.types t2 on t2.user_type_id = c.user_type_id
        WHERE t.object_id = c.object_id 
            AND c.collation_name IS NOT NULL
            AND c.max_length > 6
            and t2.name not in ('text', 'ntext')
        FOR XML PATH('') 
    ), 1, 4, '' )
) w (whereclause)
where c.columnlist is not null
ORDER BY t.name
```

Comment: Thanks would you know what I can do to this script to make the search case sensitive ?

Comment: Just add the collation right before the terminating semicolon in the select statement. WHERE ' + w.whereclause + ' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS;'